# How to write reactions spanning more lines?

Tags: mhchem

I would like to insert a few reactions in my latex document
which need to be on more lines, similarly to the reactions shown below.

What is the easiest way to achieve this?
Up to now I only wrote very single reactions using \ce{} into equations environment. Is there an easy extension to that?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to have a look at the [`chemfig`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemfig) package, particularly at its scheming commands. For details see the [`chemfig` manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/chemfig), especially part **V Reaction Schemes**. Below is an example of its usage:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig,amsmath}

\begin{document}

\schemestart
 E\phantom{I}
 \arrow{<=>[S][$K_S$]}
 ES\phantom{I}
 \arrow{<=>[*0I][*0$K_{ii}$]}[-90]
 EIS
 \arrow{<=>[S][$K_{SS}$]}[180]
 EI
 \arrow{<=>[*0$K_i$][*0I]}[90]
 \arrow(@c2--){->[$k_{\text{cat}}$]}
 E \+ P
 \arrow(@c3--){->[$k_0$]}
 EI \+ P
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, I never heard of this package before :) (I am not a chemist, so I am not expert in typesetting chemical reactions!)

Comment: @gcnieder just one more question: is chemfig compatible with mchem? I would like to avoid rewriting all the reactions I have written if possible...

Comment: You can use `chemfig` and `mhchem` side by side. Their reaction arrows look differently, though, so visually it's not a perfect match.

Comment: Hi, I just have one more question..
say I want to modify the scheme you posted so that on the vertical reaction I read E+I and ES + I, can I do that? I went through part 5 but can't really find an example...

Comment: @LucaCerone I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean... why don't you just write `E + I`?

Comment: I edited the other question, hopefully it is slightly more clear...